# How can i move a file to another directory and if the same file name exist rename old file with old_filename

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have two files in two different folders. I want to move/copy a file in first folder to second folder. If the same file names exist i want to change older file name with older_filename and move/copy new file to same directory. How can i do it?

For example I have a zip file named B FOLDER and i am going to unzip that zip folder in TEMP FOLDER then i will have almost 10 .txt files in TEMP FOLDER. Then i have a TARGET FOLDER that .txt files going to move in TARGET FOLDER from TEMP FOLDER. My question is, that files in TEMP FOLDER and TARGET FOLDER have the same name. I want to rename the files in TARGET FOLDER with old_filename then move to files in TEMP FOLDER to TARGET FOLDER without changing name. Thats what i want, if it is not unclear, sorry :) Really i tried my best.

Best regards.

EDIT 1:
Hi again. Thanks for helps it is really helpfull. I am trying a new code here:

```
forfiles /P C:\.... /S /M a1.txt /C "cmd /c rename @path old_@fname.txt"
```

Above code is changing file names in TEMP FOLDERs. But i want to change file names in TARGET FOLDERs. How can i do it  visa versa?
how about that? May be it could help to me. How can i go with that code?

Comment: by the way new file name must keep the same name, i just want to change older file name with older_filename. Thanks..

Comment: check, if destination exists with `if exist filename` and rename (`ren`) it. (overwrite `older_file` or implement a loop with a counter and rename to `older-2_file` etc), Then move/copy the source file. Come back, if you have trouble with your code and we will gladly assist you, but we will not write code for you for free..

Comment: @Stephan i am very pleasure for help, thank you. Filename is not stable, it has different names and more than one. I am going to unzip a file in temp folder, but here is the actual question, how can i compare unzipped file names between first and second folders and change the name of older file with old_filename? Can not figure it out.

Comment: Still not sure what you want. Maybe an example could help (edit your question - the comment section isn't built for that)

Comment: use a `for` loop to iterate over the files in `temp folder` (`for %%a in ("temp folder\*") do ...`) and check for each file `if exist "target folder\%%~nxa" (` <insert code for renaming here> ) <insert copy/move here>. Please come back with some code we can help you with.